Loading PPTX file in frontend from base64 encoded data in react
I am getting base64 encoded data for a PPTX file from an API in react and I need to load the PPTX in an  tag in UI.
import * as React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useLocation  } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from '../components/header.js';

export default function MainPage() {
    const [PPT_SRC, setPPT_SRC] = React.useState('');
    const location = useLocation();

    React.useEffect(() => {

        let url = 'get_data';
        url = url+'?id='+1;

        axios.get(url).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.message.PPT_SRC);

            //const linkSource = `data:application/pptx;base64,${response.data.message.PPT_SRC}`;
            //const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            //const fileName = "file.pptx";
        
            //downloadLink.href = linkSource;
            //downloadLink.download = fileName;
            //downloadLink.click();

            setPPT_SRC(response.data.message.PPT_SRC);

        }); 

    }, [location]);

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <br /><br />
            
            <div id={"second"} style={{ padding: '30px 0' }}>
                <iframe 
                    title='CI'
                    src={`data:application/pptx;base64,${PPT_SRC}`}
                    style={{ height: '80vh', width: '70vw' }}
                >
                </iframe>
                {PPT_SRC}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

The above code is not loading the PPTX file in the , but when I uncomment the code inside the axios.get() method which creates the pdf file and downloads it, it forms the PPTX and downloads it propely.
Is there a way to load the PPTX in iframe ?
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks,

You can use react-doc-view to load and render the ppt.
Install it
 npm i @cyntler/react-doc-viewer

Import it
import DocViewer, { DocViewerRenderers } from "@cyntler/react-doc-viewer";
    

Add it your component
function App() {
  const docs = [
    { uri: "https://url-to-my-pdf.pdf" }, // Remote file
    { uri: require("./example-files/pdf.pdf") }, // Local File
  ];

  return <DocViewer documents={docs} pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers} />;
}


thanks for answering. let me try this. But Is there a way to load it on iframe tag if possible.. any suggestions ?

I don't think that you can directly render ppt in iframe but if you don't want to use the library, you can use microsoft viewer. Check out this answer
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=[https://www.your_website/file_name.pptx]' width='100%' height='600px' frameborder='0'>

Thanks for replying.. i tried ur approach, it not loading the page saying "An error occurred".. One thing i noticed that, if i harcode my url to iframe src directly it loads "".. If i set the src to a object on page load and set that variable back to src, it says could not connect ""...  Any idea why this would happen ?

I think for you to view the ppt it should be public url and not private, that maybe the cause for "An error occurred". Not sure about other issue with iframe. If you want we can connect and try to solve it. You can reach out to me here
